Speed up VBA for loop essentially running a vlookup in 2 arrays and populating an output array
I am a vba amateur, so I know there is a more efficient way to code this. The code runs, but I am trying to cut down on the run time. I have two of these in a module. This one takes about 2m 50s to run, the other 1m 25s.In short, I need it to lookup an id in another sheet in the same workbook, look for criteria in other columns of that row, and then populating various columns in the first sheet where the ids match.
Here is the code:
Sub Pref()
'insert account pref data into dataset

Dim wsP As Worksheet
Dim wIP As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim bizArr As Variant
Dim outArr As Variant
Dim Searchfor As Variant
Dim p As Variant
Dim pArr As Variant

Set wsP = Sheets("Preferences")
    With wsP
    lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    pArr = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lrow, 6))
    End With
    
Set wIP = Sheets("Working Issue Pay Data")
    With wIP
    lRow2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    bizArr = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow2, 1))
    outArr = Range(Cells(1, 17), Cells(lRow2, 27))
    End With

        On Error Resume Next
           For b = 2 To lRow2
           For p = 2 To lrow
           Searchfor = bizArr(b, 1)
           If pArr(p, 1) = Searchfor Then
               If pArr(p, 3) = "ACH" And pArr(p, 5) = "Yes" Then
                   outArr(b, 1) = pArr(p, 5)
               ElseIf pArr(p, 3) = "Payment" Then
                   outArr(b, 2) = pArr(p, 5)
                   outArr(b, 3) = pArr(p, 6)
               ElseIf pArr(p, 3) = "Lien" Then
                   outArr(b, 4) = pArr(p, 4)
                   outArr(b, 5) = pArr(p, 6)
               ElseIf pArr(p, 3) = "Defer Pay" And pArr(p, 5) = "Yes" Then
                   outArr(b, 7) = pArr(p, 5)
                   outArr(b, 8) = pArr(p, 6)
            Exit For
           End If
           End If
        Next p
        Next b
 
wIP.Range(Cells(1, 17), Cells(lRow2, 27)) = outArr

End Sub

I am open to changing the code completely.
I've added Erase pArr, Erase bizArr, Erase outArr before ending the sub to see if it would help. Although, I am not sure if this is helpful, because the same bizArr and outArr is used in both subs.
Also, I have this optimizing code applied when it runs:
Public Sub OptimizedMode(ByVal enable As Boolean)
' attempt to speed up Build macro

     Application.EnableEvents = Not enable
     Application.Calculation = IIf(enable, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
     Application.ScreenUpdating = Not enable
     Application.EnableAnimations = Not enable
     Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not enable
     Application.PrintCommunication = Not enable
     
End Sub


If your code works and you're just trying to improve the run-time, your question may be better suited for Code Review.

Is there only a single match for each value of Searchfor? What is the approximate size (# of rows) for each of your datasets?  I would remove that On Error Resume Next though, or you'll never know if your code has problems and you risk getting the wrong output.

Code Review SE

Should be faster (using Match instead of the inner loop):
Sub Pref()
    Dim wsP As Worksheet, wIP As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long, b As Long
    Dim bizArr As Variant, outArr As Variant, outRng As Range
    Dim Searchfor As Variant
    Dim p As Variant
    Dim pArr As Variant, matchRng As Range

    Set wsP = Sheets("Preferences")
    With wsP
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set matchRng = .Range("A1:A" & lr)
        pArr = matchRng.Resize(, 6).Value
    End With
    
    Set wIP = Sheets("Working Issue Pay Data")
    With wIP
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        bizArr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr, 1))
        Set outRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 17), .Cells(lRow2, 27))
        outArr = outRng.Value
    End With

    For b = 2 To UBound(bizArr, 1)
        'match against a worksheet is faster than nested loop
        m = Application.Match(bizArr(b, 1), matchRng, 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then 'got a match?
            
            Select Case pArr(p, 3)
                Case "ACH"
                    If pArr(p, 5) = "Yes" Then outArr(b, 1) = pArr(p, 5)
                Case "Payment"
                    outArr(b, 2) = pArr(p, 5)
                    outArr(b, 3) = pArr(p, 6)
                Case "Lien"
                    outArr(b, 4) = pArr(p, 4)
                    outArr(b, 5) = pArr(p, 6)
                Case "Defer Pay"
                    If pArr(p, 5) = "Yes" Then
                        outArr(b, 7) = pArr(p, 5)
                        outArr(b, 8) = pArr(p, 6)
                    End If
            End Select
            
        End If 'got match
    Next b
 
    outRng.Value = outArr

End Sub

